# Random process theory: probability distribution of height vs summits

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random, random-walk, fractals

Imagine I have a matrix of height values ($z$), e.g. a surface height topography. This surface is a random process: randomly rough isotropic surface with Gaussian distribution.

What is the difference (if there is any difference) between probability distribution of height and probability distribution of summits.

Summits in $z$ are for example defined to be the maximum value of each column of the matrix, i.e. :

```
[n , m] = size(z)
summit = zeros(m);
for i = 1 : m
    summit(i) = max(z(:,i));
end
```

If not so complex up to here, I add some more concerns: My real question is, if my original topography is a fractal surface, will the summit profile be a fractal profile with the same scaling behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: I do not know much about the fractal; I can only say that in general the sample maximum has a different distribution with the original distribution.

Comment: Thanks, what I know so far, is that for a case of randomly rough isotropic surface with Gaussian distribution the summit distribution is also Gaussian (proven in some articles), but what does it say about the scaling properties of summit profile compared to height profile?!